# Is jsrender templates need to rendered under document.ready function?

Tags: jquery, jsrender

I am using jsrender to render my templates.
Find below the sample code that I am using for my project.

```
var renderHeader = function() {
    var template = $.templates("#header_template");
    var htmlOutput = template.render({data:people});
    $("#header").html(htmlOutput);        
};
```

but is above code is neccessary to call under document.ready.
By the way, I am calling it under global function.

Please Help Me Out

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive I understand your question.  If you can somehow know, for sure, that jsrender, #header_template, #header, and (since you are calling jsrender via $) jquery are loaded, then you can call your function.  The only real point to document ready is you know that everything is already loaded at that point.

But, if you are asking, e.g. "can it be called via a click event?", then the answer is "yes".

Comment: No, I just need to know that. Whether is it necessary to call template in document.ready? Coz I am just calling them under global function.

Comment: It is not necessary to call them from document ready.  document ready is just another function that is triggered by a specific event.  It is not really special.  A function triggered by a click event (for example) has the same context.  What or how is the global function being called?  It must ultimately lead up to some type of event handler I would think.